# create custom menu in views based on drupal node's cck field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a series of committees each one has multiple types of content ex: home page, members page, links page along with a cck field with the name I would like to create a menu block in views for each committees pages based on the value of the name in the cck field and print the only one block to all the pages. is their a way to use tokens in views to accomplish this or a separate module that will accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to just create a block view that displays an li list of the cck field for each committee. You can then style this like your menu.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question i did this, what I want to do is to narrow the scope of the list to just nodes related to that committee possibly by the field_committee_name cck field.

Comment: so you have a set of content types. They all share 1 cck field that links them together. Correct? You could use an argument in your view that accepts the cck field, but I'm not certian that this method is really accounted for in views. Alternatively you might consider changing the structure of your data, make a "committee" node that is maybe the homepage, and use node reference to link the other content types to that. Any reason you are not using node reference. It might make everything more sane.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it after continuing to look using views arguments and default php argument i created an if elseif statement for each committee.